# Should each question be required to post a code as part of the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request

Since this is a technical site and OBDII is a standard since 1996, shouldn't it be a requirement to post code(s) for each question, if any, rather than having to ask?

The reason I'm asking is I think it would solve problems quicker, but it appears that not everyone bothers to post code(s).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A couple of issues with making OBD-II codes mandatory:

- we can't customize the SE interface to make it mandatory, especially while we're in Beta
- not all questions require OBD-II codes
- we can't just assume that everyone has access to a scan tool. Some won't.

---

It's not all that bad having to ask for DTC's.

But we do need some kind of a meta post that can spell out why we harp on about DTC's for questions related to vehicle operability.

Answer (score 4):

I think the word you are looking for is "tag". I couldn't agree more with you that everyone who posts a question should put tags on them. That's the perfect world and it doesn't happen until someone has been around for a while to understand the process. They cannot post a question without having *some sort of tag there*.

I don't remember exactly when it happens, but at some point level (I believe 4k), a user can go directly in and edit tags directly (a hidden "edit tags" will appear to the right of the tags in a question when you hover over the location). This allows any user with the permissions to edit the tags directly without going into the question and editing directly. As a lower level user, once you are able to edit someone's post, you can go in and add/change tags.

As for *making someone add the right tags* ... that would be near impossible. Until you've been around the site for a little while, you really don't have a clue what you should be posting in the tags anyway. There would be no way to enforce something like that ... someone would have to be policing the questions to ensure the tags are right ... wait ... we already do that by updating with the correct ones. IOW, to me it's a moot point. It's a great suggestion, but in reality it would be impossible to implement.

I would like to say, thanks for being on the site with us and hanging around. We are always looking for the *fresh perspective*. If you have further Meta questions, please don't be afraid to ask. They are always welcome as are you.

Answer (score 3):

I think if it was mandatory to post a code we would see the Questions Per Day number fall off the edge of the table and go to nearly zero.

OP's frequently don't even know what a code is until you break it down for them.

IMO (not humble) making it a requirement would potentially destroy the site regarding QPD.

That being said, I've read a few of your answers and am glad to have you around.  Even though I banged on the QPD drum, this is a good question in my not so humble opinion.   :)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that and thanks for the kind words.